# boost::adaptors::strided cannot be used after boost::adaptors::transformed?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, boost, boost-range

The following does not compile on Visual Studio 2010:

```
std::vector<int> v;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) v.push_back (i);

struct TrivialTrafo {
    typedef int result_type;
    int operator () (int i) const { return 1; }
};
auto x = v | boost::adaptors::transformed (TrivialTrafo ()) 
     | boost::adaptors::strided (2);
```

The compiler complains (error message originally in German, my translation):

```
error C2664: 
'boost::range_detail::strided_iterator<BaseIterator,Category>::strided_iterator
(const boost::range_detail::strided_iterator<BaseIterator,Category> &)':
Conversion of parameter 1 from
'boost::range_detail::strided_iterator<BaseIterator,Category>' into
'const boost::range_detail::strided_iterator<BaseIterator,Category> &'
not possible 
          with
          [
BaseIterator=boost::iterators::transform_iterator<
TEST_rectnew_getRows::TrivialTrafo,std::_Vector_iterator<
std::_Vector_val<int,std::allocator<int>>>>,
Category=boost::iterators::detail::iterator_category_with_traversal<
std::input_iterator_tag,boost::iterators::random_access_traversal_tag>
          ]
          and
          [
BaseIterator=boost::iterators::transform_iterator<
TEST_rectnew_getRows::TrivialTrafo,std::_Vector_iterator<
std::_Vector_val<int,std::allocator<int>>>>,
Category=boost::iterators::random_access_traversal_tag
          ]
          and
          [              
BaseIterator=boost::iterators::transform_iterator<
TEST_rectnew_getRows::TrivialTrafo,
std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<int,std::allocator<int>>>
>,
Category=boost::iterators::detail::iterator_category_with_traversal<
std::input_iterator_tag,boost::iterators::random_access_traversal_tag>
          ]
```

I'm using Boost 1.57.

Obviously `operator |` tries to construct a `strided_range` with the wrong `Category` template parameter value?

Is this a bug, or am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, it's a bug in Neil Groves' rewrite of `strided.hpp` (since 1.56, so you could revert to that version of boost if you need to). I've submitted a ticket: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10989

One-line fix:

```
--- a/include/boost/range/adaptor/strided.hpp
+++ b/include/boost/range/adaptor/strided.hpp
@@ -603,7 +603,7 @@ namespace boost
         template<
             class Rng,
             class Category =
-                typename iterator_traversal<
+                typename iterators::pure_iterator_traversal<
                     typename range_iterator<Rng>::type
                 >::type
         >
```

Comment: Excellent. Spotted this late. +1, especially for submitting to boost

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confused. It actually works fine:

```
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct TrivialTrafo {
    typedef int result_type;
    int operator () (int i) const { return i; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) v.push_back (i);

    for (auto&& x : v | boost::adaptors::transformed (TrivialTrafo ()) 
        | boost::adaptors::strided (2))
    {
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
0 2 4 6 8
```

Looks like you expected the transformation to take an iterator instead of the range's value type?

**UPDATE** Ah, it might be a regression/change in the Boost Range library, since it *doesn't* compile **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a491b27eac07834d)</kbd>**

This means it does work with Boost 1.55, but not with whatever Coliru uses:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7a2ee559e0cf008 says that's 1.57

Comment: Thank you for trying to reproduce the error. Indeed, my example code contained, another mistake (wrong parameter type in `TrivialTrafo::operator()`). Unfortunately, this was not the source of the problem. I've updated my question. The problem remains.

Comment: @JohnB Did you read my answer? I **know** this doesn't solve the problem. I describe the factors involved (5 minutes before your comment). I'd go read the change log/release notes or file a ticket with Boost Range :)

Comment: Sorry, maybe bad English on my side. I know that you know it. I just wanted to clarify that correcting the mistake does not solve the problem here (VS 2010, Boost 1.57), either.